# CSS JQuery animate multiple div fade in and fade out in same place infinite time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to show multiple div fading in & out in same place one after another for infinite time.

I have used three div to fade in and out in same place for infinite time, one after another.

I have tried it by using animate.css file. But could not solve it.

```css
    .quote-2{
        position: relative;
        height: 100px;
    }
   
    .quote-2 p{
        text-align: right !important;
    }
    .quote-2 .quote-text1{
        display: inline;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-animation: fadeIn 4s infinite;
        animation: fadeIn 4s infinite;
    
    }
    .quote-2 .quote-text2{
        display: inline;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-animation: fadeOut 4s infinite;
        animation: fadeOut 4s infinite;
    
    }
    .quote-2 .quote-text3{
            display: inline;
            position: relative;
            -webkit-animation: fadeIn 4s infinite;
            animation: fadeIn 4s infinite;
        
        }

    @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
        0% {opacity: 0;}
        100% {opacity: 1;
            display:block;}
    }
    @keyframes fadeIn {
        0% {opacity: 0;}
        100% {opacity: 1;
            display:block;}
    }
    .fadeIn{
        opacity:0;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes fadeOut { 
        0% {opacity: 1;} 
        100% {opacity: 0;} 
    } 

    @keyframes fadeOut { 
        0% {opacity: 1;} 
        100% {opacity: 0;} 
    } 
    .fadeOut { 
        -webkit-animation-name: fadeOut; 
        animation-name: fadeOut; 
    }
```

```html
<div class="quote-2">
       <div class="quote-text1">
          <p>Commit yourself: unless a commitment is made, There are only promises and hope</p>
          <p>Peter Drucker</p>
       </div>

       <div class="quote-text2">
           <p>Do your homework: by failing to prepare, you are preparing to fail</p>
           <p >Benjamin Franklin</p>
        </div>
       <div class="quote-text3 ">
           <p>Do your homework: by failing to prepare, you are preparing to fail</p>
           <p >Benjamin Franklin</p>
        </div>
     </div>
```

I can't understand what is wrong and what to do.

Can someone kindly tell me how can i solve this ( Any kind of solution, by CSS or JQuery ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to use jquery rather than keyframes.

**HTML**

```
<p>Text 1</p>
<p>Text 2</p>
<p>Text 3</p>
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
     $("p").css("opacity", "0");
     $("p:eq("+i+")").css("opacity", "1");
     console.log("interval"+i);
     if(i == 2) {
       i = 0;
     } else {
       i++;
     }
   }, 2000);
 });
```

**CSS**

```
p {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}
```

Here is a [pen](https://codepen.io/rileyjsumner/pen/QBmMYz)

Comment: CSS is better because the browser optimises it to suit the browser.  jQuery fits all browsers, so is therefore optimised for none.  Pure CSS will always be better than jQuery.

Comment: @rileyjsumner    It works. Thanks :) Can you tell me one more thing ? In your code, what should i do if i want to slide out to right the present <p> tag and slide in from left the next <p> tag instead of  fadein/fadeout ? How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

i think you are looking for something like this.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>
  var tag1,tag2,tag3;
  $(document).ready(function(){
  tag1= $("#p1");
  tag2= $("#p2");
  tag3= $("#p3");
  tag2.fadeOut('fast')
  tag3.fadeOut('fast');
  setTimeout(StartFading,1000)
 });
 function StartFading(){
 tag1.fadeOut("slow",function(){
 tag2.fadeIn('fast',function(){
   tag2.fadeOut("slow",function(){
      tag3.fadeIn("slow",function(){
        tag3.fadeOut("slow",function(){
            tag1.fadeIn("slow",function(){
               StartFading();
            });
        });
      });
   });
  });
 });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

 <p id='p1'>This is a paragraph1.</p>
 <p id='p2'>This is a paragraph2.</p>
 <p id='p3'>This is a paragraph3.</p>

 </body>
 </html>
```

here is a jsfiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/4qxfnL9e/3/

Comment: No. Say, i want to show id="p1" first. Other two <p> tag is hidden for first time. Then id="p1" will fade out, and id="p2" will fade in on the same place where id="p1" was, neither below nor top. 
Next id="p2" will fade out and id="p3" will fade in. Then id="p3" will fade out and id="p1" will fade in. This process will continue

Answer (score 0):

The animation doesn't work due to the `display: inline;` property. Once removed the animation works as designed. You cannot animate elements with `display: inline;` This is stated clearly in the related [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/).

```css
p{
  position: absolute;
}

.block1{
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn 9s infinite;
}

.block2{
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn 9s infinite;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.block3{
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn 9s infinite;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn{
  20% {opacity: 0;}
  50% {opacity: 1;}
  60% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "block1">
    <p>
    This is line 1.
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class = "block2">
    <p>
    This is line 2.
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class = "block3">
    <p>
    This is line 3.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```